# What is the relationship between two or more blockchains?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

Suppose that we have got one blockchain in our firm.
Meanwhile, another blockchain is in use in the other firm.
If we would like to combine or relate the two blockchains, what will the structure be after the combination? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Connect them together by making them nodes on each others network.**

Firm A connects to Firm B blockchain by becoming a node on their network. 
Firm B connects to Firm A blockchain by becoming a node on their network.